# how to shortcut the imports from styled-components

Tags: import, styled-components

i have file of many styled components vars

```
export {NavHeader, MainNav, Logo, LogoContainer, NavBarUl, SubUl, Li, SubLi, NavLink, HamburgerContainer}
```

now i need to import it  to the componenets and its very huge

```
import {
NavHeader,
MainNav,
Logo,
LogoContainer,
NavBarUl,
SubUl,
Li,
SubLi,
NavLink,
HamburgerContainer,
A,
} from "../styles/Header";
```

there is a way to handle this? and import * or something?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import * as Header from '../styles/Header';
```

then you can use
`<Header.NavHeader />`

Comment: Thanks...but ita much longer to repeat it